# How to disable column-reordering in a JavaFX2 TableView?

Tags: java, user-interface, tableview, javafx-2

JavaFX2's [TableView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) features 
"Column reordering by the user at runtime".
I'd like to disable this feature for one specific table in my Application.

Looking at the API doc, there is no obvious API hook for this.
There is, however, the `columns`-property. According to the doc, it represents

> The TableColumns that are part of this TableView. As the user reorders the TableView columns, this list will be updated to reflect the current visual ordering.

Hoping that I'd at least be able to reset a change after it occurred, I tried adding a listener to reset changes after the fact.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableTest extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }


  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
    TableView tableView = new TableView();
    tableView.getColumns().setAll(new TableColumn(), new TableColumn());
    tableView.getColumns().addListener(new ListChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Change change) {
            if (change.wasPermutated()){
               change.reset();
            }
        }
    });
    stage.setScene(new Scene(tableView));
    stage.show();
  }
}
```

However, the listener aborts with an `IllegalStateException` when I ask for `wasPermutated`.
Is there a way to prevent reordering, or at least revert it programatically?

Comment: I just tried that method and the `onChanged` method does get called when moving the columns around. However I get an IllegalStateException on `change.wasPermutated()`.

Comment: In that case, my code was probably too complex. I'll set up a minimal example and continue from there.

Comment: Just made an edit to my answer and it kind of works. You need to first call `change.next()` before checking its state + moving columns seems to set the flag to added, not permutated...

Comment: Also reset does not seem to do what you think it is doing - see javadoc here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See below a SSCCE that shows that the listener gets called - but the flag is set to `added` when moving columns. Note that you need to call `next()` before using the change or you will get an `IllegalStateException`. See the [javadoc of `ListChangeListener.Change`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html) for a simple canonical example.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableTest extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
    final TableView tableView = new TableView();
    final TableColumn[] columns = {new TableColumn("1"), new TableColumn("2")};
    tableView.getColumns().setAll(columns);
    tableView.getColumns().addListener(new ListChangeListener() {
        public boolean suspended;

        @Override
        public void onChanged(Change change) {
            change.next();
            if (change.wasReplaced() && !suspended) {
                this.suspended = true;
                tableView.getColumns().setAll(columns);
                this.suspended = false;
            }
        }
    });
    stage.setScene(new Scene(tableView));
    stage.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to your comments, I have a working sample now. My code is more concise than yours and I feel it better answers the question, yet I'd like to attribute the solution to you. Is it okay if I edit your answer to show my code and mark it as accepted?

Comment: @UrsReupke Sure - my answer is only partial - you should post your answer and accept it if it does what you wanted.

Comment: /*I transformed it into a generic function*/  @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
 public static void moveableFalse(TableView tableView) {
  List<TableColumn<?, ?>> columns = new ArrayList(tableView.getColumns());
  tableView.getColumns().addListener(new ListChangeListener() {
   public boolean suspended;

   @Override
   public void onChanged(Change change) {
    change.next();
    if (change.wasReplaced() && !suspended) {
     this.suspended = true;
     tableView.getColumns().setAll(columns);
     this.suspended = false;
    }
   }
  });
 }