# How to disable the move column header functionality in javaFx table views

Tags: javafx, tableview

we found weird behaviour after moving the columns around in the table view, even the exception was fixed in u20 version. is it possible to disable the moving functionality for column header?

Comment: please refer to the below topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598639/how-to-disable-column-reordering-in-a-javafx2-tableview

Comment: thank you. it is working. but if there is multiple columns, it seems hard to handle.