# Javafx : Restrict Column rearrangement on drag and drop

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

In a tree table view, we can re-arrange the columns by dragging the column headers.
I want to restrict the user from dragging the **first column alone**. Which means my first column should be the first column all the time.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple example where I am storing the column arrangement in a temporary list and when ever we are trying to move or replace the first column we are resetting the column arrangement.

```
!change.getList().get(0).equals(col1)
```

checks if the `col1` is still at the first location after the change. If not, we replace it with the old list.

**MCVE**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FixFiestColumnTable extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final TableView tableView = new TableView();
        TableColumn col1 = new TableColumn("Col 1");
        TableColumn col2 = new TableColumn("Col 2");
        TableColumn col3 = new TableColumn("Col 3");

        tableView.getColumns().setAll(col1, col2, col3);

        tableView.getColumns().addListener(new ListChangeListener() {
            public ObservableList<TableColumn> tempList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Change change) {
                change.next();
                if (change.wasReplaced() && !change.getList().get(0).equals(col1)) {
                    tableView.getColumns().setAll(tempList);
                }
                tempList.setAll(change.getList());
            }
        });
        stage.setScene(new Scene(tableView));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no API for that. A solution according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598639/how-to-disable-column-reordering-in-a-javafx2-tableview) is to revert the changes using a ChangeListener.

In your case you'd have to check if the 1st column changes and only revert then.

Here's an example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TreeTableTest extends Application {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final TreeTableView treeTableView = new TreeTableView();

        TreeTableColumn c1 = new TreeTableColumn("1");
        TreeTableColumn c2 = new TreeTableColumn("2");
        TreeTableColumn c3 = new TreeTableColumn("3");
        TreeTableColumn c4 = new TreeTableColumn("4");

        treeTableView.getColumns().setAll(c1, c2, c3, c4);

        treeTableView.getColumns().addListener(new ListChangeListener() {
            public boolean suspended;

            @Override
            public void onChanged(Change change) {

                change.next();

                if (change.wasReplaced() && !suspended) {
                    List<TreeTableColumn> oldList = new ArrayList<>(change.getRemoved());
                    List<TreeTableColumn> newList = new ArrayList<>(treeTableView.getColumns());

                    // first column changed => revert to original list
                    if (oldList.get(0) != newList.get(0)) {
                        this.suspended = true;
                        treeTableView.getColumns().setAll(oldList);
                        this.suspended = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        stage.setScene(new Scene(treeTableView));
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```