# Disable column rearrangement of tableview, javafx

Tags: javafx, tableview

I want to disable column rearrangement for all the column of table view and its GUI while dragging columns. Even I disable column rearrangement, user can still drag column header around table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable column-reordering in a JavaFX2 TableView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598639/how-to-disable-column-reordering-in-a-javafx2-tableview)

Comment: Yes it is but not totally what i want. I disable the change after rearrange the column but i want completely to disable rearrange. There is still we can drag and drop column but it won't change anything in table.

Comment: You could consume the mouse dragged event.